# JAGS code for estimating group means with Beta distribution

Tags: r, percentage, beta, jags

I'd like to estimate the means and sd's of percent canopy cover for 13 sites (9 are birds and 4 are potential habitats) using JAGS. I'm using a beta distribution to account for the fact that the data are bound by 0 and 1.

I have code for the model statement that works perfectly for other distributions (Poisson and log-normal) and I was attempting to adapt that code but I failed miserably.

Below are the R code, the model statement, and the data. I'm using R 3.1.1 in Windows Vista. If you could look at the model statement and straighten me out I would be very thankful.

Thanks,

Jeff

```
######## MODEL ##############
model{
  for (i in 1:227) {
    log(mean[i]) <- a[site[i]] 
    cover20p[i] ~ dbeta(1, 0.5)   
  }
  for (i in 1:13){
    a[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau) 
    median[i] <- exp(a[i])
  }
  sd ~ dunif(0, 10) 
  tau <- 1 / (sd*sd) # precision
} 

#########  R  code ########## 
frag <- read.csv("f:\\brazil\\TIandFRAG.csv", header=T)
library(R2jags)
library(rjags)
setwd("f://brazil")
site <- frag$site
cover20p <- frag$cover20p/100
N <- length(frag$site)

jags.data <- list("site", "cover20p")
jags.params <- c("median", "test100MF","test100MT","test100fc","test100fa", 
"test100gv","test100hm","test100mc", "test100ca","test100ct", "test10MF",
"test10MT", "test10fc","test10fa", "test10gv", "test10hm", "test10mc", "test10ca", "test10ct", 
"test1MF", "test1MT", "test1fc",  "test1fa",  "test1gv", "test1hm", 
"test1mc", "test1ca", "test1ct", "t1est1_con","t2est10_con","t3est100_con",
"t4est1_100","t5est1_10","t6est10_100")
#inits1 <- list(a=0, sd=0)
#inits2 <- list(a=100, sd=50)
#jags.inits <- list(inits1, inits2)

jags.inits <- function() {
  list(a=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), sd=1)}

jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params,
n.iter=1000000, n.burnin=20000, model.file="fragmodelbeta.txt")

my.coda <- as.mcmc(jagsfit)
summary(my.coda, quantiles=c(0.05, 0.25,0.5,0.75, 0.95))
print(jagsfit, digits=3)

##### DATA ###################    
structure(list(site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L
), canopy = c(0.95, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.35, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 
0.95, 0.55, 0.9, 0.85, 0.7, 0.65, 0.05, 0.6, 0.999, 0.999, 0.85, 
0.9, 1e-04, 0.45, 0.999, 0.7, 0.95, 0.5, 0.95, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 
0.4, 0.85, 0.6, 0.95, 0.75, 0.9, 0.85, 0.75, 0.7, 0.85, 0.3, 
0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.75, 0.95, 0.9, 0.05, 0.85, 0.6, 0.65, 
0.5, 0.85, 0.95, 0.85, 0.25, 0.75, 0.999, 0.65, 0.95, 0.8, 0.9, 
0.6, 0.8, 0.999, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.999, 0.95, 0.4, 0.999, 0.999, 
0.95, 0.45, 0.2, 0.7, 0.95, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.85, 0.55, 1e-04, 
0.25, 0.45, 0.999, 0.95, 0.999, 0.9, 0.6, 0.35, 0.95, 0.3, 0.999, 
0.999, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 0.999, 0.7, 0.999, 0.9, 0.999, 0.4, 0.55, 
0.8, 0.7, 0.999, 1e-04, 0.8, 1e-04, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8, 0.75, 1e-04, 
0.45, 0.1, 1e-04, 0.4, 0.55, 0.4, 0.999, 0.9, 0.9, 0.15, 0.55, 
0.35, 0.9, 0.65, 0.25, 0.999, 0.85, 0.999, 0.95, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 
0.2, 0.95, 0.999, 0.999, 0.25, 0.85, 0.5, 0.8, 0.75, 0.85, 0.7, 
0.95, 0.05, 0.65, 0.65, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.65, 0.4, 0.6, 
0.9, 0.85, 0.75, 0.5, 0.65, 0.999, 0.65, 0.55, 0.75, 0.4, 0.9, 
0.35, 0.999, 0.999, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.95, 0.95, 0.55, 0.7, 0.85, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.65, 0.999, 0.6, 0.5, 0.999, 0.8, 0.999, 0.45, 0.999, 
0.999, 0.8, 0.85, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.5, 0.6, 0.15, 
0.75, 0.6, 0.1, 0.05, 1e-04, 0.999, 0.6, 0.1, 0.35, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.9, 0.55, 0.65, 0.9, 0.4, 0.999, 0.65, 0.5, 0.8)), .Names = c("site", 
"canopy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -227L))
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong with this code? Is it throwing an error (if so, what is the error?) or giving you results that you weren't expecting (if so, what were you expecting and how did the results differ?)?

Comment: The obvious thing was that R/JAGS initialized the model then gave results instead of running a model (and taking an hour or so to do it). Then I expected the results to be bound by 0 and 1 but they were off. I know the model statement is not correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have cover20p as one of the variables, but have the data for canopy in the frag data.frame. I suspect you want `canopy[i] ~ dbeta(1,0.5)` in your model specification, and `canopy <- frag$canopy` and `jags.params = "median"` in your r code.

Comment: Thanks Jim. The variable issue was my oversight since I created a new dataframe and didn't change the name of the variable (the original data frame has 28 columns). Just assume the model statement is completely wrong. The only thing I think is right is the fact that I use a beta distribution for the likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a logit model for your probabilities. Maybe something like the following.

First, I convert your canopy observations back to the format that I suspect they began in, i.e. the number of canopy hits out of 20 samples at each site. I set 0.0001 to 0 and 0.999 to 1, and multiply the other `canopy` values by 20.

```
d$hits <- ifelse(d$canopy < 0.05, 0, ifelse(d$canopy > 0.95, 20, d$canopy * 20))

M <- function() {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    hits[i] ~ dbin(p[site[i]], 20)
  }
  for (j in 1:nsites) {
    logit.p[j] ~ dnorm(mu, sigma^-2)
    logit(p[j]) <- logit.p[j]
  }
  mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001) # uninformative prior for grand mean of logit(p)
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 10) # uninformative prior for sd of logit(p)
}

j <- jags(list(site=d$site, hits=d$hits, n=nrow(d), nsites=length(unique(d$site))), 
          NULL, 'p', M)

plot(j$BUGSoutput$summary[-1, '50%'], pch=20, xlab='site', xaxt='n', las=1, 
     ylim=c(0, 1), ylab=expression("p (median" %+-% "95% credible interval)"))
segments(1:13, j$BUGSoutput$summary[-1, '2.5%'], 
         y1=j$BUGSoutput$summary[-1, '97.5%'])
axis(1, 1:13, 1:13)
```

[image]