# Hierarchical model using JAGS for R shows wrong number of means

Tags: jags, rjags, hierarchical-bayesian

[image]

I have 2 columns of data, `y` and `grp` and I am trying to create a `JAGS` model which is shown above. `grp` is group and I have 5 groups. The following code is from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bridgesampling/vignettes/bridgesampling_example_jags.html). I am using this code because the description there under the heading `Model and Data` looks almost like this hiererchical model.

But I get only one `mu` when I view the summary. There should be 5 `mu's`, one for each group. Can someone correct the code ? You may also point to a similar example available elsewhere and I could try to modify it. I am missing something in the code and I believe the code could be like the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574323/jags-code-for-estimating-group-means-with-beta-distribution) but when I modify it like that I don't seem to get proper means even though there are 5 means.

Not sure if this question belongs in math stackexchange.

> 

```
mod_string = " model {
   for (i in 1:length(y) {
    theta[i] ~ dnorm(mu[grp[i]], invTau2)
    y[i] ~ dnorm(theta[i], 1/sig)
  }
  mu ~ dnorm(0, 1e6)
  invTau2 ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.3/2.0)
  tau2 <- 1/invTau2

  invgamma2 ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 2.1/2.0)
  sig = 1/invgamma2
    } "
```

> 

```
summary(mod_sim)

Iterations = 2001:52000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 3 
Sample size per chain = 50000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

         Mean    SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
mu  5.639e-07 0.001 2.582e-06      2.582e-06
sig 1.570e+00 1.888 4.874e-03      7.068e-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using nested indexing, where `grp` is a vector of length `y` and describes what group each element `y` belongs to. If each group needs it's own mean then you need to generate 5 `theta` priors. This is most easily done in it's own loop. Thus, your model string would look something like:

```
mod_string <- " model {
   # loop for y
   for (i in 1:length(y)) {
     y[i] ~ dnorm(theta[grp[i]], sig)
   }
   # loop for theta
   for (g in 1:ntheta){
     theta[g] ~ dnorm(mu, tau2)
   }
   # other priors. JAGS uses precision so you need to use the reciprocal 
   # of 1e6 for the variance of mu.
   mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.000001)
   invTau2 ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.3/2.0)
   tau2 <- 1/invTau2

   invgamma2 ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 2.1/2.0)
   sig <- 1/invgamma2
} "
```

Note that you also need to supply the scalar `ntheta` to the model, which would be the number of unique groups (in this case `ntheta = 5`). Now if you track `theta` you will end up with 5 estimates whereas `mu` has 1 estimate (it is the grand estimated mean of all groups).

Comment: `y` and `grp` are columns of the data. Each `y` belongs to a group. I think this is what you meant. When I execute the code and track theta I get proper values. I think.